# string/array operations in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to so something like that in bash (.bashrc) so the alias is set based on which comp the user logged in. I don't know how to get the 210 from 10.0.0.210 and then the best way of going through of the list 'user=xxx'

```
$radek ='210'
$mike ='209'


#SSH_CLIENT='10.0.0.210 53039 22'  <--- system variable
$user = based on the 4th part of IP so 
   $user = radek if 210
   $user = mike if 209

alias sites='cd /var/lib/code/'+$user
```

### so the final alias looks likeg

'cd /var/lib/code/**radek**' if logged from **210** computer

'cd /var/lib/code/**mike**' if logged from **209** computer

---

### Final code thanks to @Dennis Williamson

```
users[210]=radek
users[209]=mike

octet=($SSH_CLIENT)    # split the value on spaces
#octed=${octet[0]##*.}        # extract the last octet from the ip address
alias sites='cd /var/lib/code/'${users[${octet[0]##*.}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
users[210]=radek
users[209]=mike

octet=($SSH_CLIENT)    # split the value on spaces
octet=${octet[0]##*.}  # extract the last octet from the ip address
alias sites='cd /var/lib/code/'${user[octet]}
```

Another way to assign users:

```
names=(bob jim anne kelly rick)
octet=211
for name in ${names[@]}
do
    users[octet++]=$name
    if (( octet > 255 ))
    then
        echo "Error: range limit exceeded"
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: wow, wow, wow. It's very nice. I had to modify the code little bit to make it work. Thank you so much. `users[210]=radek
users[209]=mike

octet=($SSH_CLIENT)    # split the value on spaces
#${octet[0]##*.}        # extract the last octet from the ip address
alias sites='cd /var/lib/code/'${users[${octet[0]##*.}]}
`

Comment: @Radek: Oops, sorry, it was a typo on my part. Your version works, but I'm editing the answer to show what I had intended.

Comment: don't be sorry :-) You helped me so you can be only proud of yourself. The most elegant answer ...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
export user=`env|grep -i SSH_CLIENT|cut -d' ' -f1|cut -d'.' -f4`
```

and remove the `+` in the alias. It should just be

```
alias sites='cd /var/lib/code/'$user
```

Based on your edit hopefully this should work:

```
temp_user=`env|grep -i SSH_CLIENT|cut -d' ' -f1|cut -d'.' -f4`
user=`env|awk -F= "/=$temp_user/"'{print $1}'`
```

Comment: what about the name? I need to substitute the 210 with radek but I want to make it general as I there is few of us :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have a hard requirement for the format to store the user to ip mapping, the following sample script will work :

```
user_210="radek"
user_209="mike"

function define_alias
{
        local ip_last_part=`echo $1 | cut -d ' ' -f1 | cut -d '.' -f4`
        eval user=$`echo "user_$ip_last_part"`
        echo "User '$user' identified for ip ending in '$ip_last_part'"
        alias sites="cd /var/lib/code/$user"
        echo "Alias defined : `alias sites`"
}


#Exampe usage :

# will come from env
export SSH_CLIENT='10.0.0.210 53039 22'
define_alias $SSH_CLIENT


export SSH_CLIENT='10.0.0.209 53039 22'
define_alias $SSH_CLIENT
```

If you dont want to use the function, you copy the code in the function out side and use domino's suggestion to get the last part of the IP. Like this :

```
user_210="radek"
user_209="mike"
ip_last_part=`env | grep -i SSH_CLIENT | cut -d ' ' -f1 | cut -d '.' -f4`
eval user=$`echo "user_$ip_last_part"`
echo "User '$user' identified for ip ending in '$ip_last_part'"
alias sites="cd /var/lib/code/$user"
echo "Alias defined : `alias sites`"
```

HTH,

[Madhur Tanwani](http://madhurtanwani.blogspot.com)